# How to make dependent picklist dynamically in the pagebloack table in Viasualforce

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, wrapper-class, dependent-picklist

I wanted to display dependent Picklist values in the Pageblock table. 
for this i created a wrapper as

```
public class AcccWrapper
    {
        public Account Acc1{get;set;}   
        public List<SelectOption> 1List{get;set;}
        public Map<id,List<SelectOption>> 2List{get;set;}

        public SoldToPayerWrapper(Account Acc,List<SelectOption> lst1,Map<id,List<SelectOption>> lst2)  
        {         
            Acc1= Acc;
            1List = lst1;
            2List = lst2;
        }
    }
```

Page

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wrapper1}" var="rtype1">
   <apex:repeat value="{!wrapper1[rtype1]}" var="items1" >
      <tr>
         <td >
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!items1.Acc.Id}" id="theLink2">{!items1.Acc.Name} </apex:outputLink>
         </td>
         <td >
            <apex:selectList id="soldToId" value="{!items1.Acc.User1__C}" >
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!items1.1List}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
         </td>
         <td >
            <apex:selectList id="payerId" size="1" title="" >
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!items1.2List[items1.Acc.User1__C]}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr/>
   </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

in the `map<id,list<selectoption>>` im adding list1 id and list2 values. 
so based on the list1 value, list2 should display.

please provide me suggestions how to acheive this. [image]

Comment: in wrapper class take a method that will get the option based on selected value on first picklist.. You need to call wrapper class method on change of first picklist..

Comment: Thanks Ratan. I tried that.. but that works fine if there is a single record. But i wanted that to work for multiple records.

Comment: SFDC It will work for multiple records.. Since you are calling method inside wrapper class and you will select only for current row picklist.. Can you please your part of code you have tried?

Comment: <apex:repeat value="{!wrapper1}" var="rtype1"><apex:repeat value="{!wrapper1[rtype1]}" var="items1" ><tr><td ><apex:outputLink value="/{!items1.Acc.Id}" id="theLink2">{!items1.Acc.Name} </apex:outputLink></td><td ><apex:selectList id="soldToId" value="{!items1.Acc.User1__C}" ><apex:selectOptions value="{!items1.1List}"/>  </apex:selectList></td><td ><apex:selectList id="payerId" size="1" title="" ><apex:selectOptions value="{!items1.2List[items1.Acc.User1__C]}"/> </apex:selectList> </td></tr><tr/></apex:repeat></apex:repeat>